# How to catch an error and stop my bot from crashing

Tags: discord.js

So basically I'm looking for a way to stop my bot from crashing because of user error or a bug in my code. What I want to bot to do is catch an error and respond to the message sender saying "Error! ${errormessage}". hopefully you understand what I mean.

Comment: Could you please provide the code that makes your bot crash? Thanks

Comment: try catch or .catch are basic stuff, learn JS and you will know

Answer (score 0):

You could use `try-catch` or simply `.catch`

This is a basic javascript topic, you can read and learn error handling [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

Point to note is, you need to locate the line which is throwing the error by analyzing the error log.

Keep in mind you can only prevent the bot from crashing by using the above stated methods on **runtime errors** otherwise known as exceptions (ex: unhandledPromiseRejection, thrown during runtime), you cannot use this method on errors like `TypeError`, `SyntaxError` etc (Errors thrown while parsing the code), such errors can only be fixed by manually identifying the line and applying appropriate fix